# Changing content and phone number depending on where website is accessed from

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

I am just starting to use Google Adwords, and I want to know if I can put some type of cookie or redirect that shows a different phone number for my website if someone comes from Google Adwords, and then have the normal phone number for a organic search.

For example,

If someone clicks my Adwords url, they see the phone number 888-555-1111

If someone clicks through organic search they the phone number 800-111-2222

Is there a way to do this?

Here's a website that does this: http://www.protectyourhome.com/

Here's my website: http://www.securemyhome.com/

Thank you.

Comment: It's about redirecting using some type of PHP or Javascript and setting URL parameters. It's not about 'Adwords' that's just a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you append a url parameter to your adwords url?

e.g. http://www.securemyhome.com?src=adwords

And then you can check on your page if it exists. If it does, show them an alternate phone number. This can be achieved using javascript or jquery.

```
if (param exists)
  // append alternate phone number
else
  // append regular phone number
```

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how I can do it this way?